# Override css of parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a full screen background video which I have added a "dimmed" div over the top of, to dim the video with a semi-transparent black fullscreen div. Code:

```
.dimmed:after {
  content: " ";
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="full_size dimmed">
        <video autoplay loop poster="assets/images/home_page/polina.jpg" id="bgvid">
            <!--<source src="polina.webm" type="video/webm">-->
            <source src="assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="not_dimmed">
            <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" ><h5 id="app-name" class="nav-item clickable white-text medium-text left-text">{{APP_NAME}}</h5></a>
            <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" ><h5 (click)="clicked()" id="sign-in-button" class="nav-item clickable brand-colour-text medium-text right-text with-border">{{REGISTER_TEXT}}</h5></a>
            <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" ><h5 class="nav-item clickable white-text medium-text right-text">{{LOGIN_TEXT}}</h5></a>
            <a href="#home_page_footer" ><h5 class="nav-item clickable white-text medium-text right-text" >{{BLOG_TEXT}}</h5></a>
        </div>

    </div>
```

I want the `anchor` text that I have placed over the top of the video background to not be dimmed. As you can see I have added a not_dimmed class and tried to override the dimmed styles with no dimming.

However it is still dimmed. How would I "undim" the text?

All css:

```
.vertical-center {
    height: 100%;
    /*Fallback for vh unit 
    You might also want to use
    'height' property instead.

    Note that for percentage values of
    'height' or 'min-height' properties,
    the 'height' of the parent element
    should be specified explicitly.

    In this case the parent of '.vertical-center'
    is the <body> element */

    /* Make it a flex container */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex; 

    /* Align the bootstrap's container vertically */
    -webkit-box-align : center;
    -webkit-align-items : center;
    -moz-box-align : center;
    -ms-flex-align : center;
    align-items : center;

    /* In legacy web browsers such as Firefox 9
    we need to specify the width of the flex container */
    width: 100%;

    /* Also 'margin: 0 auto' doesn't have any effect on flex items in such web browsers
    hence the bootstrap's container won't be aligned to the center anymore.

    Therefore, we should use the following declarations to get it centered again */
    -webkit-box-pack : center;
    -moz-box-pack : center;
    -ms-flex-pack : center;
    -webkit-justify-content : center;
    justify-content : center;

    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/*large text on the home page*/
#motto-text {
    height: calc(100% - 160px);
    /*font-family: 'woodford_bourneregular', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;*/
}

.white-text {
    color: white;
}

.brand-colour-text {
    color: #95F666;
}

.light-text {
    font-weight: 100;
}

.medium-text {
    font-weight: 300;
}

/*text on the left side of the page*/
.left-text {
    margin: 60px 0px 0px 60px; float: left;
}

/*text on the right side of the page*/
.right-text {
    margin: 60px 60px 0px 0px; float: right;
}

.italic-text {
    font-style: italic;
}

.clickable {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.with-border {
    border: 1px solid #95F666;
    border-radius:3px;
    padding: 12px;
}

#sign-in-button {
    margin-top: 48px;
}

.nav-item:hover {
    color: #95F666;
}

#app-name:hover {
    color: white;
}

#sign-in-button:hover{
    background-color: #95F666;
    color: dimgray;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    h3 {
        font-size: 17px;
    }

    h4 {
        font-size: 13px;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    #app-name {
        display: none;
    }

    right-text {
        margin: 60px 30px 0px 30px;
    }
}



.full_size {
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover; 
}

/*subtract the height of the footer to get an accurate vertical center*/
#home_page_background {
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    #home_page_background {
        background-image: url("../assets/images/home_page/bg_ls_strawberry_dark.jpg");
    }
}

@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    #home_page_background {
        background-image: url("../assets/images/home_page/bg_p_strawberry_dark.jpg");
    }
}

.dimmed:after {
  content: " ";
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.not_dimmed {
  z-index: 11;
  background: transparent;
}

video#bgvid { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url(../assets/images/home_page/polina.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
}

/*for ie 9*/
video { display: block; }

@media screen and (max-device-width: 800px) {
    html {
         background: url(../assets/images/home_page/polina.jpg) #000 no-repeat center center fixed;
    }
    #bgvid {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens if you add `z-index:-1` to `.dimmed:after` ?

Comment: Please post the CSS for the classes present in your HTML sample

Comment: .not_dimmed{ position;relative; z-index: 100; }

Comment: Here is a fiddle with what you posted so far. How can we make something out of that? ... https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/dqg7ypny/

Comment: @LGSon Just posted the css. Cheers.

Comment: @Aziz Oh just tried that and it worked!

Comment: you're welcome. BTW you could have used the `:before` pseudo element instead of the `:after`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply the background-color-dim from the :after-element to the anchors' container instead.